# How to merge three select queries into one in order to achieve the desired result as below in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

The purpose is to push 'N' flag on the first negative occurrence of Planned Delta and Actual Delta respectively for each project.
'Y' flag should be pushed in all the rest rows.
Rank column defines the order and Project ID defines the data of one project.

Only select queries can be used

Use below table structure
'''

```
CREATE TABLE payBackTable (projectID varchar2(10), quarterYear varchar2(10), Rank int, planned_delta int, actual_delta int ) 
INSERT INTO payBackTable values
( 'P001','Q1-2017', 1, 2000, 900)
( 'P001','Q2-2017', 2, 18000, 800)
( 'P001','Q3-2017', 3, 0, 7000)
( 'P001','Q4-2017', 4, 9000, -90)
( 'P001','Q1-2018', 5, -10, 9000)
( 'P001','Q2-2018', 6, 100, 70)
( 'P001','Q3-2018', 7, -90, -900)
( 'P001','Q4-2018', 8, 200, -8)
( 'P002', 'Q3-2016', 1, 1000, 90 )
( 'P002', 'Q4-2016', 2, -200, 90 )
( 'P002', 'Q1-2017', 3, 4000, -500 )
( 'P002', 'Q2-2017', 4, 10, -90 )
( 'P003', 'Q3-2021', 1, -10, 700 )
( 'P003', 'Q4-2021', 2, 100, -800 )
( 'P003', 'Q1-2022', 3, -100, -900 )
( 'P003', 'Q2-2022', 3, -90, 100 )
```

'''

Source Table

| Project ID | Quarter-Year | Rank | Planned Delta | Actual Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Q1-2017 | 1 | 2000 | 900 |
| P001 | Q2-2017 | 2 | 18000 | 800 |
| P001 | Q3-2017 | 3 | 0 | 7000 |
| P001 | Q4-2017 | 4 | 9000 | -90 |
| P001 | Q1-2018 | 5 | -10 | 9000 |
| P001 | Q2-2018 | 6 | 100 | 70 |
| P001 | Q3-2018 | 7 | -90 | -900 |
| P001 | Q4-2018 | 8 | 200 | -8 |
| P002 | Q3-2016 | 1 | 1000 | 90 |
| P002 | Q4-2016 | 2 | -200 | 90 |
| P002 | Q1-2017 | 3 | 4000 | -500 |
| P002 | Q2-2017 | 4 | 10 | -90 |
| P003 | Q3-2021 | 1 | -10 | 700 |
| P003 | Q4-2021 | 2 | 100 | -800 |
| P003 | Q1-2022 | 3 | -100 | -900 |
| P003 | Q2-2022 | 4 | -90 | 100 |

Desired Result

| Project ID | QuarterYear | Rank | Planned Delta | Actual Delta | Planned Flag | Actual Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Q1-2017 | 1 | 2000 | 900 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q2-2017 | 2 | 18000 | 800 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q3-2017 | 3 | 0 | 7000 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q4-2017 | 4 | 9000 | -90 | Y | N |
| P001 | Q1-2018 | 5 | -10 | 9000 | N | Y |
| P001 | Q2-2018 | 6 | 100 | 70 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q3-2018 | 7 | -90 | -900 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q4-2018 | 8 | 200 | -8 | Y | Y |
| P002 | Q3-2016 | 1 | 1000 | 90 | Y | Y |
| P002 | Q4-2016 | 2 | -200 | 90 | N | Y |
| P002 | Q1-2017 | 3 | 4000 | -500 | Y | N |
| P002 | Q2-2017 | 4 | 10 | -90 | Y | Y |
| P003 | Q3-2021 | 1 | -10 | 700 | N | Y |
| P003 | Q4-2021 | 2 | 100 | -800 | Y | N |
| P003 | Q1-2022 | 3 | -100 | -900 | Y | Y |
| P003 | Q2-2022 | 4 | -90 | 100 | Y | Y |

I have been able to achieve table to push the desired result using three different queries/batch jobs but not sure how to implement this in a single query/batch job.
To push 'N' flag in Planned Flag

```
select projectID,quarterYear, 'N' from(
select  projectID, quarterYear,
Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY projectID ORDER BY to_number(Rank)) 
as rownumm from payBackTable 
where  to_number(planned_delta) < 0) where  rownumm = 1
```

To push 'N' flag in Actual Flag

```
select projectID,quarterYear, 'N' from(
select  projectID, quarterYear,
Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY projectID ORDER BY to_number(Rank)) 
as rownumm from payBackTable 
where  to_number(actual_delta) < 0) where  rownumm = 1
```

To push 'Y' flag in Planned Flag and Actual Flag

```
select projectID,
quarterYear,
case planned_Flag when NULL then 'Y' ELSE planned_Flag END, 
case actual_Flag when NULL then 'Y' ELSE actual_Flag END
from payBackTable
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and complete a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) for the desired result.

Comment: I have made the correction, Please suggest

Comment: You also need CREATE TABLE / INSERT as follows: `CREATE TABLE X(ProjectID varchar2, QuarterYear varchar2, Rank int, PlannedDelta int, ActualDelta int )`
`INSERT INTO X( ProjectID, QuarterYear, Rank, PlannedDelta, ActualDelta )`
`select 'P001', 'Q1-2017', 1, 2000, 900 from dual union all`
`select 'P001', 'Q1-2017', 2, 18000, 800 from dual union all`
...
`select 'P003', 'Q1-2022', 4, -90, 100 from dual`

Comment: Hi @GauravKanodia Sorry, I red it three times and still can't get it. As far as I see you need to set "N" only when value is negative, right?

Comment: I need to set N on the first occurence of negative value.

Comment: _"I have made the correction"_.   No, you have not posted the requested CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Comment: @EdStevens Please check now

Comment: Both your `create` and `insert` are invalid - you need to supply the size for varchar2 columns, and Oracle doesn't support that syntax for multiple-row inserts. Are you confusing Oracle with MySQL, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a ranking for each value within the project *and* based on the sign of each value:

```
select projectid, quarteryear, rank, planned_delta, actual_delta,
  dense_rank() over (partition by projectid, sign(planned_delta) order by rank) as flag1,
  dense_rank() over (partition by projectid, sign(actual_delta) order by rank) as flag2
from paybacktable
order by projectid, rank
```

| PROJECTID | QUARTERYEAR | RANK | PLANNED_DELTA | ACTUAL_DELTA | FLAG1 | FLAG2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Q1-2017 | 1 | 2000 | 900 | 1 | 1 |
| P001 | Q2-2017 | 2 | 18000 | 800 | 2 | 2 |
| P001 | Q3-2017 | 3 | 0 | 7000 | 1 | 3 |
| P001 | Q4-2017 | 4 | 9000 | -90 | 3 | 1 |
| P001 | Q1-2018 | 5 | -10 | 9000 | 1 | 4 |
| P001 | Q2-2018 | 6 | 100 | 70 | 4 | 5 |
| P001 | Q3-2018 | 7 | -90 | -900 | 2 | 2 |
| P001 | Q4-2018 | 8 | 200 | -8 | 5 | 3 |

...

And then use those as part of case expressions; if that rank i1 *and* the value is negative, then it's the first negative value:

```
select projectid, quarteryear, rank, planned_delta, actual_delta,
  case
    when sign(planned_delta) = -1
      and dense_rank() over (partition by projectid, sign(planned_delta) order by rank) = 1
    then 'N'
    else 'Y'
  end as planned_flag,
  case
    when sign(actual_delta) = -1
      and dense_rank() over (partition by projectid, sign(actual_delta) order by rank) = 1
    then 'N'
    else 'Y'
  end as actual_flag
from paybacktable
order by projectid, rank
```

| PROJECTID | QUARTERYEAR | RANK | PLANNED_DELTA | ACTUAL_DELTA | PLANNED_FLAG | ACTUAL_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Q1-2017 | 1 | 2000 | 900 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q2-2017 | 2 | 18000 | 800 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q3-2017 | 3 | 0 | 7000 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q4-2017 | 4 | 9000 | -90 | Y | N |
| P001 | Q1-2018 | 5 | -10 | 9000 | N | Y |
| P001 | Q2-2018 | 6 | 100 | 70 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q3-2018 | 7 | -90 | -900 | Y | Y |
| P001 | Q4-2018 | 8 | 200 | -8 | Y | Y |
| P002 | Q3-2016 | 1 | 1000 | 90 | Y | Y |
| P002 | Q4-2016 | 2 | -200 | 90 | N | Y |
| P002 | Q1-2017 | 3 | 4000 | -500 | Y | N |
| P002 | Q2-2017 | 4 | 10 | -90 | Y | Y |
| P003 | Q3-2021 | 1 | -10 | 700 | N | Y |
| P003 | Q4-2021 | 2 | 100 | -800 | Y | N |
| P003 | Q2-2022 | 3 | -90 | 100 | Y | Y |
| P003 | Q1-2022 | 3 | -100 | -900 | Y | Y |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0ff0eef604b749d670746b2f9711832)

Answer (score 0):

```
select P1.projectID, P1.quarterYear, P1.Rank, P1.planned_Delta, P1.actual_Delta,
    case when Rank = X1.RankMin then 'N' ELSE 'Y' END plannedFlag , 
    case when Rank = X2.RankMin then 'N' ELSE 'Y' END actualFlag 
from payBackTable P1 
left join (
    select projectID, min(Rank) RankMin
    from payBackTable P2 
    where Planned_Delta < 0
    group by projectID
    ) X1 on P1.projectID = X1.projectID

left join (
    select projectID, min(Rank) RankMin
    from payBackTable P2 
    where Actual_Delta < 0
    group by projectID
    ) X2 on P1.projectID = X2.projectID
```